# Modify a value conditional on group and other values in the group using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data to the form (`df1`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep( c('id_1', 'id_2') , c(3,3)),
                  item = c('item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3') ,
                  time_1 = c( 1:3 , 2:3 , 1) , time_2 = c( 1:3 , 1, 3 , 1))
```

```
    id   item time_1 time_2 = expected result to replace time_1
1 id_1 item_1      1      1
2 id_1 item_2      2      2
3 id_1 item_3      3      3
4 id_2 item_1      2      1
5 id_2 item_2      3      3
6 id_2 item_3      1      1
```

The grouping variable is `id`. I wish to check that `item_1` has the lowest time (`time_1`). If not, I shall assign the lowest time to it. Such as for `item_1` for `id_2` which is assigned 1 instead of 2.

I found a way to do it by creating an extra variable (`min`) and `ifelse`:

```
 df1 %>%
  group_by( id ) %>%
  mutate( min_ = min( time_1 ) ) %>%
  mutate( time_1 = ifelse( ( item == 'item_1' ) & ( time_1 != min_ )  , min_ , time_1 ) )
```

I found however this method a bit brutal, and it may not use dplyr potential to deal with data manipulation. Does anybody know a dplyr solution to this?

Comment: Can you share `dput(df1)`?

Comment: Is it what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` by groups:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(time_1 = replace(time_1, item == "item_1", min(time_1)), .by = id)

#     id   item time_1
# 1 id_1 item_1      1
# 2 id_1 item_2      2
# 3 id_1 item_3      3
# 4 id_2 item_1      1
# 5 id_2 item_2      3
# 6 id_2 item_3      1
```

or use `slice_min()` by groups and then `rows_update`:

```
df1 %>%
  slice_min(time_1, by = id) %>%
  mutate(item = "item_1") %>%
  rows_update(x = df1, by = c("id", "item"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer which is great. I will have to work on it as it isn't to familiar to me. But it is the kind of answer I expected.

Comment: @marc I update a new solution with `replace`. Maybe it's easier to understand.

Comment: The `replace` option makes more sens to me and is tidier, thanks